# Keyboard on android device causes password input field to disappear (ionic app)

Tags: android, android-layout, ionic3, android-softkeyboard

I have an ionic app and when i build for android they keyboard causes some content issues.
When I press they phone number input the page does not focus on the phone number but its still visible, however when i press next to go to the password it tries to focus on the password field however there is white space an the whole input field is not visible.

```
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm">

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
          <p class="phone-prompt">Login with your Phone Number</p>
          <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                    <ion-select interface="popover" formControlName="options" >
                            <ion-option value="961">+961</ion-option>
                            <!--<ion-option value="380">+380</ion-option>-->
                    </ion-select>
                    <ion-input class="input-field phone-text" type="text" formControlName="phoneNum" placeholder="Your phone number"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                    <ion-input  class="input-field" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter a password"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center>
            <button type="submit" ion-button class="login-button" outline color="primary" (click) = "loginAction()">
                Login
            </button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center>
            <a class="forgot" (click) = "forgotPassAction()" >
              Forgot password?
            </a>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
```

And the scss of this code

```
page-login {

  .phone-prompt{
      margin-top: -20px;
      color: color($colors, spin-main);
  }

  .cyan{
      color: color($colors, spin-main);
      font-size: 22px;
  }

  .grey{
      color: #D3D3D3;
  }

  .login-button{
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-transform: none;
      margin-top: 8%;
      width: 130px;
      height: 30px;
      color: #6568b5;
  }

  .line{
      margin-top: 18px;
  }


  .line2{
      margin-top: 18px;
  }

  .phone-text {
      position: relative;
  }

}
```

I have tried manipulating different keyboard setting in the AndroidManifest by changing

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

into

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but it does not solve the issue it just stops focusing and leaves content under the keyboard

ionic version: 3.20.0

cordova version: 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things i found out that when the keyboard is visible there is white space padding from the scroll div i sloved the issue by adding this to the css

```
ion-content > div {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

This solved the white space issue and now the app looks much better